# How to select specific time for list of times?

Tags: mysql, time

The problem sounds like: Select the patients with the 14:00:00 booking time.

**Patient Table**

```
PatientID
Patient1
Patient2
Patient3
```

**Booking Table**

```
PatientID   TimeCode
Patient1    123
Patient2    124
Patient3    125
```

**Workhour Table**

```
Hours       TimeCode
14:00:00    123
14:45:00    124
14:00:00    125
```

I already have a code that works:

**Query**

```
select Bookings.PatientID 
from Patient, Bookings, Workhour 
where Workhour.Hours='14:00:00' 
and PatientID=Bookings.PatientID 
and Bookings.TimeCode=Workhour.TimeCode;
```

The problem is it also display people with `14:45:00` when I only need `14:00:00` times. How do I do it?

Comment: Your query (although poorly written) should work (*Never use commas in the `FROM` clause).  Perhaps sample results or a SQL Fiddle would explain what is going wrong.

Comment: This query will return nothing at all, because of error in syntax. Column `PatientID` in `WHERE` is ambiguous. But if change condition from `PatientID=Bookings.PatientID` to `Patient.PatientID=Bookings.PatientID` seems it must work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use ANSI joins to make the code easier:

```
SELECT b.PatientID 
FROM Patient p
JOIN Bookings b
    ON p.PatientID = b.PatientID
JOIN Workhour h
    ON b.TimeCode = h.TimeCode
WHERE h.Hours='14:00:00'
```

For your query you don't need to join with Patient

```
SELECT b.PatientID 
FROM Bookings b
JOIN Workhour h
    ON b.TimeCode = h.TimeCode
WHERE h.Hours='14:00:00'
```

Why you get more rows than expected I don't know. Add `CREATE TABLE` statements and some sample data as `INSERT` statements to your question and I'll have a look.